# Is there any IDE for OSDEV?

Tags: ide, osdev

Is there any IDE to create operating systems in C/C++/Assembly?
If there, please tell me how to setup it for OSDEV or point me to a good tutorial.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge there really aren't any IDEs specifically geared toward operating systems development, although there are several options available for the languages most commonly used for such work. In general there's not much of a difference between OSDev and any other kind of C/C++/Assembly development, so any ordinary IDE equipped for those languages should suffice. My personal favorite is [Eclipse CDT](https://www.eclipse.org/cdt/), which, like other Eclipse products, can be extended with plugins for Assembly development, etc.

Some other IDEs worth mentioning are [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/), [CLion](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/), or even command-line text editors like `vim` and `nano`. *Whatever you are most comfortable with for other C/C++ development should work just fine for OS development.*

Where OSDev and ordinary C/C++ development *may* differ, however, is in the build process. Usually a C/C++ project is compiled into a binary file which is then executed on the machine, while a kernel image will be designed to either function as a mountable boot drive, or be loaded by another bootloader. This requires more than just compilation, and as far as I know, there aren't any IDEs which will immediately support, for example, creating a disk image from compiled code. For this, I recommend GNU make, which can run Makefiles that contain the steps to incrementally build and run your operating system. A good resource for learning about how to write makefiles can be found [here](http://nuclear.mutantstargoat.com/articles/make/), with the [official manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) serving as extra guidance.

In short, any functional C/C++ IDE will suffice for OS development, while a slightly more complex build system will be required to actually run/test your operating system.

Comment: I also want to add that when it comes to things like linker scripts and assembly there really isn't that good of a support in these IDEs. I recommend extensible environments which provide syntax support for these as well. VSCode is a good choice if you want to start with a more familiar enviroment.